# Node.js socket.io functions are not sent between server and client

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

First of all I would like to apologize for any mistakes in my question, this is my first fellas!

I am trying to test a connection between my server and client using the following code.

Here's how it works: A socket is initiated on a certain port, the client then attempt to connect on that port, the connection is partially successful meaning that 'node server.js' starts the connection and when I go on my browser to 'localhost:8000' the html page is generated, however when I click the button Nothing happens at all.

index.html code

```
<html>
<head>
    <script  src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var socket = io.connect("localhost:8000");
    $("#join").click(function() {
    var name = $("#name").val();
    if (name != "") {
        socket.emit("join", name);
      }
    });
    socket.on("update", function(msg) {
        $("#msgs").append("<li>" + msg + "</li>");
    });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Yor name" id="name">
    <input type="button" name="join" id="join" value="Join!">
    <ul id="msgs">
    </ul>
</body>
```

server.js code

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    http = require('http'),
sio = require('socket.io');

var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-type': 'text/html'});
res.end(fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/index.html'));
});
server.listen(8000, function() {
console.log('server is running');
});
var socket = sio.listen(server);

socket.on("connection", function (client) {
  client.on("join", function(name) {
  client.emit("update", name + "You have successfully sent your first message.");

  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you named your variables made it confusing. The only problem in your code is that this code:

```
socket.on('connection', handler);
```

Should be changed to:

```
socket.sockets.on('connection', handler);
```

In most cases, as well as the examples on the website, the `EventEmitter` would typically be named `io.sockets`. In your case, you are doing the equivalent of `io.on('connection', handler);` which is why it is not working correctly.

Comment: Are you sure the connection is actually being established? What does your browser debug show?

Comment: It says "Failed to load resource" http://0.0.31.64:8000/socket.io/1/?t=1379332632021

Comment: Do you know which transport it's using? Websockets, long polling, etc?

Comment: I'm not sure actually, would you like me to try something?

Comment: Could you try adding a protocol to the `io.connect()` on your client? Like so: `io.connect('http://localhost:8000/');`.

Comment: Whoa! It worked!! I have been pulling my hair out for the past 3 hours over this :/
Thank you Very Much!
One last thing please, can you tell him how to pick your last comment as the solution? :p